# Can't change objects variable with objects function in C++

Tags: c++, oop

Trying to create a graph of matrixes after changing one vertex of the matrix I add them to graph. Here is the code for it.

```
explicit Node(const State &head) : head(head) {
    this->no_of_child = 0;
}

void AddChild(const State &state){

    Node new_node(state);
    children.push_back(new_node);
    no_of_child = children.size();

}

void NextStates (){
    int n = head.getN();
    int ** matrix = head.getMatrix();

    //For all empty places in matrix create a new node if it meets the constraints.
    //Then add that node to the graph.
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
                matrix[i][j] = 2;

                State child(n, matrix, head.getRows(), head.getCols());
                if(child.isLegal()){
                    AddChild(child);

                    cout<<"========================================="<<endl;
                    children[no_of_child-1].getHead().printState();
                }
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
    }

    cout<<"=========================================\n"
          "========================================="<<endl;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < no_of_child ; i++) {
        children[i].getHead().printState();
        cout<<"========================================="<<endl;
    }

}
```

First `printState()` prints exactly what I want.
But after the loop ends second `printState()` prints matrix but nothing has changed. First I see it changed but then it is just a bunch of copy of my initial matrix. I couldn't even make a comment on this. Please help.

Comment: in the first loop you only access the last entry of `children` in the second loop you access `children[i]`. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like your `head.getMatrix()` is not returning the right pointer or your `State` constructor is not cloning the matrix as it should, could you post your code for those?

Comment: @GBrandt no it isn't the problem. See, if I print them after I added them to the graph, I see it did what I wanted. But if I want to reach them after the graph is complete I see all matrixes are the same as initial matrix.

Comment: Yes, then you do `matrix[i][j] = 0;` and get the original matrix back to it's original state, which could be affecting the matrix inside `new_child` too if it's not copied the right way (by allocating a new matrix in memory and copying stuff there).

Comment: Understood. How would you do it then. I can't change the initial matrix. I need to change just one vertex in matrix for every new child.

Comment: Your `State` class should create a clone of the matrix it receives, calling [`memcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) for every row/column. Then you can change the original matrix at will without affecting the child nodes.

Comment: `(Node*)realloc(..)`. Why not use C++ with `std::vector` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 because I am not really familiar with C++. I always worked with C and this is the way I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'new_child' is a temporary variable in the first for loop, and, in the 'AddChild()' function, the node is 'deep copy' -ed to the children list. So, you need a deep copy constructor of 'Node'.

Comment: So you mean when temporary variable is gone, my node also lose its inner "Node" object?

Comment: Yes, if you have not a deep copy, your state was lost after exit the 'if' field.

Comment: I understood. So what do you recommend instead? What do you mean by deep copy?

Comment: @Yuanhui I'm not sure that's the case, `children[no_of_child-1] = node;` should be calling the copy constructor (which should "deep copy" stuff) for `Node` if `children` is a `Node` array. @Ekrem Solmaz do you have a copy constructor for your `Node` class?

Comment: A better way is to save a pointer of Node to the 'children' list to avoid to write a deep copy of Node.

Comment: @GBrandt No I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Following is wrong with lifetime of object:

```
void AddChild(Node &node){
    no_of_child++;
    children = (Node*)realloc(children, sizeof(Node) * no_of_child);
    children[no_of_child-1] = node;
}
```

It would require placement new.

Simpler is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Node> children;
```

and then:

```
void AddChild(const Node& node){ children.push_back(node); }
```

Comment: I did it but the same problem still continues. It changes first then it goes back to first state.

Comment: Does `Node` respect rule of 5/3/0 ?

Comment: It doesn't I think. But I am trying to understand that rule for half an hour. I don't get why it can cause my problem.